# согласование верно? «разработано 144 дополнительных общеобразовательных программ»

Tags: согласование, числительные

Разработано 144 дополнительных общеобразовательных программ или дополнительные общеобразовательные программы?

Answer (score 3):

Отбросьте избыточное (для решения проблемы), и получите:

*Разработано 144 программ,* - ну и куда это годится? Раз четыре, то программы. А пять (конечное) - программ.

*Разработано 145 программ*.

141 программа,

142--144 программы,

145--149 программ.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше подойдет такой вариант **с согласованием во множественном числе:** Разработаны 144  дополнительные общеобразовательные программы.